# DFS in any order for cleaning every room on a grid?

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, backtracking, maze

Consider a problem where a "robot cleaner" is placed on a room modeled as a grid. Each cell in the grid can be empty or blocked and all accessible cells are connected, meaning, all empty cells will be **accessible** by the robot regardless of its starting position.

We are told that the robot cleaner can only take one of four actions:

- `robot.move()` to move forward (returns true if next cell is open and robot *moves* into the cell, returns false if next cell is obstacle and robot *stays* on the current cell.)
- `robot.turn_left()` to turn left (90 degrees, without moving)
- `robot.turn_right()` to turn right (90 degrees, without moving)
- `robot.clean()` to clean the current cell in the grid

We are asked to design an algorithm for the robot to clean the **entire room**.

---

Every solution I have found to this problem considers exploring the adjacent cells (to the cell being currently visited) in either **clockwise** or **counter-clockwise** direction (i.e. the so called wall-following principle), with respect to the current direction of the robot in the cell (e.g. example below in Python). Why?

E.g. Why wouldn't regular DFS (and thus choosing adjacent cells in **any** order (e.g. trying all 4 directions e.g. up/down/right/left **regardless of the current position**) not work here?

---

```
def clean_room(robot):

    def go_back():
        robot.turn_right()
        robot.turn_right()
        robot.move()
        robot.turn_right()
        robot.turn_right()

    def backtrack(cell = (0, 0), d = 0):
        visited.add(cell)
        robot.clean()

        # Always going clockwise : 0: 'up', 1: 'right', 2: 'down', 3: 'left'
        for i in range(4):
            new_d = (d + i) % 4
            new_cell = (cell[0] + directions[new_d][0], \
                        cell[1] + directions[new_d][1])

            if not new_cell in visited and robot.move():
                backtrack(new_cell, new_d)
                go_back()
            # turn the robot following chosen direction : clockwise
            robot.turn_right()

    # Going clockwise : 0: 'up', 1: 'right', 2: 'down', 3: 'left'
    directions = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]
    visited = set()
    backtrack()
```

Comment: DFS (and BFS) are valid search algorithm to transverse all connected cells.

Comment: @c0der BFS requires teleportation.

Comment: @MattTimmermans or backtracking, right ? Very inefficient of course.

Answer (score 1):

DFS will work no matter what order you use to try adjacent cells.  It is not particularly efficient, however, because it can spend a lot of time backtracking over cells that it's already explored.  With DFS, after every "child" cell, you have to re-enter your parent, which has already been visited.

Using a different strategy can be up to twice as fast, requiring half as many moves.  Those other strategies are usually more complicated, however.

One significant and easy improvement is to use DFS, but when you have to backtrack, you first figure out where you're going to end up, and then find the shortest path to get there.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Just so that I am clear: 1) Going clockwise will work (the code I posted above) 2) You are saying that DFS will also work, but will be slower and 3) You are also separately saying there are other room (graph) traversal strategies that are more efficient here (than #1 and #2) but that are more complicated?

Comment: Well, I can't vouch for the code you posted, but otherwise yes to all 3.  You may want to lookup flood-fill algorithms.  There are lots, and some of them are robot-compatible